# What is 0 degree isotherm and how to calculate it?

Tags: meteorology, glaciology, mountains, snow

I want to look at different areas of alpine glaciers and understand the position of 0 degree isotherm to do a comparative climate analysis. Given the mean annual air temperature and altitude, how do i calculate a 0-degree isotherm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, whether there is more to this question, but the 0-degree isotherm is simply the set of height values for each point in the 2D domain (earth's surface) at which a value of 0 degrees is present (the 0 levelset of the three dimensional temperature field with respect to height).